# cannot convert string to datetime using ParseExact

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

I have a string like this (in 12 hr clock) in my XML config data file:

```
expires="10/27/2014 2:42:57 PM"
```

I want to assign that value as a (datetime) member of a class like this:

```
 Common.SOExpiries = 
     DateTime.ParseExact(gSet.Attribute("expires").Value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",    
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but I am getting the error 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'

what am I doing wrong here?

This is in the UK btw, so the CultureInfo should be ok

Comment: " PM" is not understood by "hh:mm:ss" use "hh:mm:ss tt"

Comment: why in gods green earth someone down graded the question!?!?

Comment: I'm guessing either it's my repuation that precededs me, or (more likely) it could be that it looks like I didn't do enough research to find out what was wrong...this isn't the case, I did the research, but didn't get the part about the 12 hours clock!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"
```

as you forget about `tt`to indicate AM/PM, and `h` because you have 1-12 hours, not 01-12 hours format. Consider if your seconds and minutes should be also `s` and `m`.

Comment: it still throws the same error even if I do this: `Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.ParseExact(gSet.Attribute("expires").Value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));`

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the AM / PM portion as well.

```
Common.SOExpiries = 
 DateTime.ParseExact(gSet.Attribute("expires").Value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",    
 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```